# How do I disable a crazed mouse/touchpad (Ubuntu 16.04)?

Tags: 16.04, usb, mouse, touchpad

A bit like other questions on touchpads but with a twist,  I think.  The touchpad in this Lenovo IdeaPad Z360 had been acting up  even when it ran Windows 7.  I switched to an external USB optical mouse, but the thing often disappears, buttons stop working  or pointer starts moving on its own.

xinput lists the following pointer devices:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

"USB OPTICAL MOUSE" is external mouse.   Is it possible that the two devices are fighting for control of the pointer and buttons?  How can I disable "PS/2 Generic Mouse" and leave  "USB OPTICAL MOUSE" reign unchallenged?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `system settings` -> `mouse` and touch-pad.

Then Disable **"turn off"** touch-pad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   It does not work in this case.  The touchpad (probably broken)  is not being detected correctly.  It shows on the xinput output as "PS/2 Generic Mouse".  Is it possible to disallow the driver behind it?

Answer (score 0):

Blacklisting module **psmouse** solved all the erratic mouse behavior I was experiencing.

The broken touchpad was being identified by command **xinput** as **PS/2 Generic Mouse** instead of **AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad**.  In the latter, the touchpad could have been disabled in system **settings -> mouse & touchpad**.

For instructions on how to blacklist a kernel module:

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-blacklist-a-module-on-ubuntu-debian-linux